# $A = \{e_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $e_i = (0,...0,1,0,0,...)$. Show that $\overline{span(A)}=c_0$, set of infinite sequences that converges to 0

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $A = \{e_i:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$ where $e_i = (0,...0,1,0,0,...)$. It has $1$ in the $j^{th}$ entry.

Define $span(A)$ as the set consisting of all finite linear combinations of elements in $A$.

Show that $\overline{span(A)}=c_0$, i.e. the closure of $span(A)$ is the set $c_0$ which is the set of all infinite complex sequences $x=(x_1,x_2,...)$ such that $x_i \rightarrow 0$ as $i \rightarrow \infty$.

---

I have no idea where to start...

Comment: Closure with respect to what?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo Supremum norm. $\|x\|=\sup\{|x_i|:i\in \mathbb{N}\}$

Answer (score 2):

First show that every sequence converging to $0$ is in the closed span of $A$. Let $$\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in c_0\;,$$ and note that for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, the sequence $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n,0,0,0,\ldots\rangle$ is in the span of $A$.

Then show that every sequence in the closed span of $A$ converges to $0$. If $x=\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is such a sequence, it’s the limit of a sequence $\langle x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ of points in the span of $A$: if $x^{(n)}=\langle x_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$, there is some $m_n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $x_k^{(n)}=0$ for all $k\ge m_n$. If the sequence $x$ doesn’t converge to $0$, there are an $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $\langle x_{k_j}:j\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ such that $|x_{k_j}|\ge\epsilon$ for each $j\in\Bbb Z^+$. Does the $\epsilon$-nbhd of $x$ contain any of the points $x^{(n)}$?